# Firebase auth reports <keychain-error> on iOS while working fine on Android (Flutter)

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

Trying to use firebase auth on flutter (email/password auth)

```
      try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: txt.text,
          password: pass.text,
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text('Wrong password'),
        ));
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(e.code),
        ));
      }
    }
```

Getting Firebase Auth Exception with error code `'keychain-error'`

Auth method not matters, i'm getting same with Google auth

moreover: if i will enter wrong password it will report wrong password error, so everything is fine with contacting firebase server (i've installed firebase into project properly)

Same code works fine on Android

Answer (score 0):

For those with the same issue, read this:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9392#issuecomment-1238751984

> From Firebase 9.6.0 onward, macOS targets depending on Firebase should be signed with a provisioning profile that has the Keychain Sharing capability enabled. This will be mentioned in the release notes and documentation.